# Test a value with if

Tags: twig

I want to test in object, if a value is in a array.

`products.name` is a property of an object with as value the string 'AMUSE BOEUF'. I've tried the following snippet, but it's not working

```html
{% if products.name == ['AMUSE BOEUF'] %}
    GOLDEN PRIZE
{% endif %}
```

I also tried with a numerical like this and this is working,

```
{% if products.id == 1090 %}
    WINNER IS 1090
{% endif %}
```

but what can i do for a string value?

Answer (score 2):

Since `['AMUSE BOEUF']` is an array you should use the `in` operator instead:

```
{% if products.name in ['AMUSE BOEUF'] %}
    GOLDEN PRIZE
{% endif %}
```

or don't use an array:

```
{% if products.name == 'AMUSE BOEUF' %}
    GOLDEN PRIZE
{% endif %}
```

To be honest, you shouldn't hardcode such logic in templates anyway. This should be extracted to a service instead. For instance, you could develop your own [twig test](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/index.html) called `won` and write it like this, notice beautiful semantics:

```
{% if product has won %}
    GOLDEN PRIZE
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried both, 'solution 1 and 2) nothing happen ? i don't know why ??

Comment: I don't get solution 3, I nned  to find by the name on this problem

Comment: The suggested solutions definitely work. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/sijll3)

Comment: ... but in my page it's not working, i don't know why